# What makes something a joint distribution, for example is $P(X+Y \le a)$ considered a joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Many times I see questions in the following format:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with the following joint distribution
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> d,  & a\le x, y \le b \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Compute the probability density function of $X + Y$.

or compute $X + Y \le 4$, or $XY$, or $X + Y^2$, or $X - Y$, etc.

My question is in all of these cases, is the thing I am being asked to compute, for example $X + Y$, itself a joint distribution? I know this sounds very simplistic but I am genuinely confused, as I thought we already had the joint distribution, in my example, $d$? Is this some sort of new joint distribution that we are making out of the old joint distribution, or is it called something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exmaple, $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is a 2-dim joint density that can give you a 1-dim (marginal) density $f_X(x)$ for $X$ (as if $Y$ doesn't exist), via $f_X(x) = \int f_{XY}(x,y) dy$. Similarly, it can give you a 1-dim density $f_Y(y)$ for $Y$ (as if $X$ doesn't exist).

Now consider another $W \equiv X+Y$. It is a single random variable which should have its own 1-dim density $f_W(w)$. You can obtain this via performing variable transformation (as in calculus) on $f_{XY}(x,y) \mapsto f_{WZ}(w,z)$, where $Z$ is another random variable that is auxiliary. From this new joint density you will get the desired $f_W(w) = \int f_{WZ}(w,z) dz$ as if $Z$ never existed in the first place.

Here your $W = X+Y$ happens to be like change of coordinates, and the accompanying $Z$ is often conveniently chosen to be $Z \equiv X- Y$. Of course, the choice of $Z$ is arbitrary, and $Z = X$ or $Z = Y$ are both good.

There are other ways to obtain $f_W(w)$ besides integrating out the auxiliary variable from a 2-dim joint density. The point is, you can visualize in this case that $W$ is a new coordinate axis (just like $X$) that points along the diagonal direction. Just like how $X$ has its own 1-dim density $f_X$, this $W$ has its own density $f_W$.

Comment: So it's not a joint distribution, rather it's own single distribution...

Comment: Related question- where $W=X+Y$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ was a certain joint distribution, lets say $d$, and one needed to compute $E(X+Y)$, would one use the density of $W$ or the joint distribution $d$ for the probability? What about in a case of $E(XY)$?

Comment: Either will do for $E(X+Y) = E(W)$. If you already know the marginal density $f_W$ for $W$, then you can use $E(W) = \int f_W(w) dw$. Alternatively, since expectation is linearly additive, $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ so if you already know both $f_X$ and $f_Y$ then you can directly use them. Otherwise, you can obtain $f_X$ and $f_Y$ from the 2-dim joint $f_{XY}$.

Comment: Note that the notational convention of $f_{XY}$ actually refers to the 2-dim joint $f_{X,Y}$ and NOT the 1-dim density of the product $Z \equiv XY$, which has its own 1-dim density $f_Z$.

Comment: There are several ways one can calculate $E(XY)$ from the joint $f_{X,Y}$ or the marginal $f_Z$. None of the correct methods has anything to do with $W = X+Y$.

Comment: So when computing $E(XY)$, one would need to find the new density of $Z=XY$, and using the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ by itself would not work, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. [See this for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) for one of the approaches. The general idea you absolutely need to learn is that, for whatever function $g(X,Y)$ you want to compute its expectation $E[g]$, this thing $G \equiv g(X,Y)$ is itself a random variable thus has its own distribution. There's actually [a name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). As you can see, the warning message from the system has appeared, and we better stop this back and forth. You can make new post for further questions.